# Gradle build error after BSOD(java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After BSOD(blue screen of death) I have next gradle build error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> - What went wrong: java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
> - Try: Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Exception is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
at  org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.TreeSnapshotRepository.removeTreeSnapshotUsage(TreeSnapshotRepository.java:85) 
at  org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedFileSnapshotRepository.remove(CacheBackedFileSnapshotRepository.java:47)                   
at  org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository$1$1.run(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:81)
at  org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)               
at  org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:192)
at  org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:175)
at  org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:106)
at  org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:187)
at  org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:60)
at  org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository$1.update(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:66)
at  org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.afterTask(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:135)
at  org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:68)
at  org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
at  org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
at  org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at  org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
at  org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at  org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
at  org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
at  org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
at  org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
at  org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
at  org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
at  org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
at  org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
at  org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
at  org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
at  org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
at  org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
at  org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
at  org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
at  org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
at  org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
at  org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
at  org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
at  org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
at  org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
at  org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
at  org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
at  org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
at  org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
at  org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
at  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:46)
at  org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
at  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
at  org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
at  org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
at  org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
at  org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
at  org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
at  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
at  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
at  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
at  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
at  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
at  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
at  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
at  org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
at  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
at  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
at  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
at  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
at  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
at  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
at  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
at  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
at  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
at  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:237)
at  org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
at  org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
```

> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 7.294 secs

P.S: I tried to clean project, sync gradle, rebuild project and nothing of this didn't help me.

Answer (score 21):

I suppose, this could be caused by corrupted Gradle cache. You can try to delete it, to do that, you have to close your Android Studio, then stop Gradle deamon with `gradle --stop` command and then delete `.gradle` folder from the root of your project. After that you have to start Studio and try to build it again.

Comment: How do I stop the Gradle Daemonin Android Studio after I've closed it? Where do I type the command?

Comment: It's possible that invalidating caches will do the trick. I ended up needing to do it after removing the gradle cache anyways.

Comment: Deleting your project's .gradle folder is the way to solve this. (This answer should be picked as the right one.)

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio/ Intellij press cmd + shift + a (ctrl + shift + a), type `Invalidate caches`, and press Invalidate and restart button.

Did the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

In such cases "File -> Invalidate caches and restart" option usually helps me.