# Android Studio project build failed on startup-Null pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I am getting the following error on Android Studio ver 2.2 startup and when it tries to build the project. Thanks in advance.

> Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
> - Try:
>   Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Exception is:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.TreeSnapshotRepository.removeTreeSnapshotUsage(TreeSnapshotRepository.java:85)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedFileSnapshotRepository.remove(CacheBackedFileSnapshotRepository.java:47)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository$1$1.run(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:81)
>   at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
>   at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:192)
>   at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:175)
>   at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:106)
>   at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:187)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:60)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository$1.update(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:66)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.afterTask(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:135)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:68)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
>   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
>   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
>   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
>   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
>   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
>   at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
>   at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>   at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>   at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
>   at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
>   at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>   at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
>   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
>   at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
>   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
>   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
>   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
>   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
>   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
>   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
>   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
>   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
>   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
>   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
>   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:46)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>   at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:237)
>   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
>   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)

Comment: Check below answer, it might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320630/gradle-build-error-after-bsodjava-lang-nullpointerexception-no-error-message

Answer (score 0):

Try one of them. 
 1. (On Top Bar) Build-> Clean Project 
 2. Build-> Rebuild Project
 3. File-> Invalidate Caches

Comment: Tried all the 3 methods..but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Gradle command:

```
./gradlew assembledebug --info --stacktrace --
```

or check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39281447/5539802).

Comment: Thanks man...deleted .gradle folder and rebuild it..worked for mr

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using Glide for showing the image. But for some reason, I replaced the Glide library with the Picasso library. When I removed the Glide dependency, I was getting the same error. So I just put the Glide dependency back in even though I was using Picasso for showing images now. Everything works fine again. It maybe due to some dependency issues.